# Find the maximum integer, $m$ which is $a^m \equiv 3^{24} \pmod {961}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

$3$ is the primitive root for $mod$ $961$. Let $a^m \equiv 3^{24} \pmod {961}$ for primitive root, $a(\neq 3)$ for $mod$ $961$. Find the maximum integer $m$ satisfying $0\leq m <930$. (Here $961=31^2$).

Since $a$ is primitive root, $\exists$ $k$   $s.t.$  $a^k \equiv 3 \pmod {961} $ and $gcd(k,930)=1$. Clearly $gcd(k,930)=1$, There is a inverse of $k$ in ring $\mathbb{Z}_{930}$. So we can derive $m\equiv 24k \pmod{930}$ from $a^{m} = 3^{24} \equiv a^{24k}  \pmod {961} $. More simplify this $m\equiv 6k \pmod{930} $. From here, my question starts. The answer sheet suggested $924$ is the maximum value. I can't agree that because $960 = 6\cdot 160$ and $1 \neq (160,930)$.  Considering $930$ case $k$ would be $160$. But As I formerly said, $k$ must be coprime with the $930$. But $160$ isn't. So my answer is  $906 (= 6\cdot 151)$. Is my answer right?

Best regards

p.s.) The reason for the "$m\equiv 6k \pmod{930} $".

Considering the index(discrete log), $ind_a$

$a^{m} = 3^{24} \equiv a^{24k}  \pmod {961} \Rightarrow m\equiv24k\pmod {930}$. So the $m\in\langle 24\rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}_{930}$. Plus Since the $gcd(24,930)=6$, $\langle 24\rangle = \langle 6\rangle$. Therefore $m\in\langle 6\rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}_{930}$. That is $m\equiv6k \pmod {930}$.Plus from the $(k,930)=1$, Able to get my conclusion.

Comment: I think your answer is correct because $\phi(31^2)=930\Rightarrow 3^{930}\equiv 1\bmod 31^2$ we can rewrite: $3^{906}\equiv 1\bmod 31^2$ and $3^{24}\equiv 1\bmod 31^2$, the multiplication of these two gives $3^{930}\equiv 1\bmod 31^2$ , so maximum of m can be $906$.

Comment: @sirous, Thanks for comment. But Since $3$ is the primitive root, I think "$3^{24} \equiv 1 \pmod {961} $" does not hold. Considering the definition of the primitive roots, Order of the $3$ should be $930$ not the any divisor  of the $24$.

Comment: You can't say $k$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\Bbb Z_{961}$ unless $(k,961)=1$.

Comment: Why does $m\equiv 6k\pmod{930}?$

Comment: @Cpc, noob that was typo. My intent was $\mathbb{Z}_{930}$. Sorry. Second if we get the discrete log for $a$ , we can get the $m\equiv 6k$

Comment: @Cpc, More specifically speaking From  $m \equiv 24k$ and $gcd(930,24)=6$, we can derive that result under the hypothesis $k$ and $930$ is coprime .

Comment: There's a mistake (or two).  I can't follow what you're doing.

Comment: @Cpc Let me give time edit my post. Then please tell me concrete point what I've wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137984/discussion-between-cpc-and-kechang-lee).

Comment: @CPC. I edited my post. Let's continue our discussion either chat room or this post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ is primitive and $a^m$ has order $465=930/(24,930)=930/6=155$, then $(m,930)=6$.

The biggest multiple of $6$ not divisible by $31$ or $5$, and $\lt930$, is $924$.

There will be a primitive $a$ for which $a^{924}\equiv 3^{24}\pmod{961}$.

Comment: Why does $a^m$ has order $465$? Following your comment,  I think the order of it have to be $40$.

Comment: O.K. As you can see the question requires the "$m$" provided that $a^{928} \equiv 3^{24}$

Comment: Oops,  $(930,24)=6$.

Comment: So, $a^m$ has order $155$.  Sorry.

Comment: $$3^{930}\equiv 1\bmod 31^2$$

Multiplying both sides by $3^{24}$ we get:

$$3^{954}\equiv 3^{24}\bmod 31^2$$

$954=924+30\Rightarrow 954\equiv 924\bmod 30$, so we may write:

$$3^{924}\equiv3^{954}\equiv 3^{24}\bmod 31^2$$

Comment: @sirous $3$ has order $930$, so this isn't right.